# What is the correct syntax for the item.publish command to update a hosted feature layer?

Tags: arcgis-online, update, arcgis-python-api, hosted-feature-layer

Trying to use the code provided at the bottom of this entry
[overwrite feature class in arcgis online using python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208763/overwrite-feature-class-in-arcgis-online-using-python)
to overwrite an existing hosted feature layer in my ArcGIS Online content.
I have zipped up a file geodatabase which contains one feature class.

The item.update command results in a True response

But, when I reach the publish command, I get an "`error file_type must be provided`".
I have tried many iterations of file_type (eg. `fileType=fileGeodatabase`, `file_type=fileGeodatabase`, etc)
but keep getting various errors.

My code:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS(url="myarcgisonline", username="myusername",password="mypassword")
datafile = r"D:\....\upload.zip"
item = gis.content.get("the item id for my existing hosted feature layer")
item.update({},datafile)
item.publish(overwrite=True)
```

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
> 1, in    File "C:\Program
> Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis_*init*_.py",
> line 10118, in publish
> raise ValueError("A file_type must be provide, data format not recognized") ValueError: A file_type must be provide, data format not
> recognized

How can I determine the correct syntax for the last item.publish command?

(I have tried using the editing setting of the hosted feature layer to both enabled and disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.Item.update).

Sometimes the `fileType` cannot be identified in which case, you can provide this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ESRI documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.Item.publish) linked by CaptDragon - there is an optional parameter you can add to specify a file type in item.publish().

So your publish command would look like:

`item.publish(overwrite=True, file_type="serviceDefinition")`

(Note: `file_type` not `fileType`)

Other valid values for `file_type` are: `serviceDefinition`, `shapefile`, `csv`, `excel`, `tilePackage`, `featureService`, `featureCollection`, `fileGeodatabase`, `geojson`, `scenepackage`, `vectortilepackage`, `imageCollection`, `mapService`, and `sqliteGeodatabase`

Using this optional parameter helped me get past the ValueError but resulted in a further unspecified error, so YMMV.